# Difference between protected and without

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, kotlin

Hello everybody I have this code in Kotlin for Android but I don't know why it does not work. Here is my code:

```
package com.test.tictac

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    protected fun buClick(view: View) {
        val buSelected = view as Button
        var cellID = 0
        when(buSelected.id) {
            R.id.bu1->cellID = 1
            R.id.bu2->cellID = 2
            R.id.bu3->cellID = 3
            R.id.bu4->cellID = 4
            R.id.bu5->cellID = 5
            R.id.bu6->cellID = 6
            R.id.bu7->cellID = 7
            R.id.bu8->cellID = 8
            R.id.bu9->cellID = 9
        }

        Toast.makeText(this,"ID:"+ cellID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of things and according to me when I remove protected for the function `buClick` it works but is there a way to make workable with `protected`? Thank you very much!

PS : This is the xml :

```
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.tictac.MainActivity">

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu1"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:onClick="buClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu2"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:onClick="buClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu3"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:onClick="buClick" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu4"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:onClick="buClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu5"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:onClick="buClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu6"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:onClick="buClick" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu7"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:onClick="buClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu8"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:onClick="buClick" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bu9"
            android:layout_width="40pt"
            android:layout_height="40pt"
            android:layout_marginRight="3pt"
            android:onClick="buClick" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: The `protected` modifier means that the method will be visible to this class and its subclasses. Your `MainActivity` class is final (because classes in Kotlin are final by default), so it won't have any subclasses, and using `protected` here doesn't make any sense (even if it worked).

Answer (score 4):

The [`android:onClick`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick) takes a method name as value.

> This name must correspond to a public method that takes exactly one parameter of type View.

Adding `protected` to the method reduces the visibility from `public` which is required by the framework.

Answer (score 2):

It has something to do with access modifiers. Protected methods can only be seen by subclasses (classes that extend the class in which the method exists) or by other classes in the same package. And as already mentioned by @tynn , the android:onClick requires the methods called to be public, or else it won't be able to use it. 
I advise that you read more into access modifiers, and when to use them.